# Looking for information on Android's Sync Manager

Tags: android, synchronization

I haven't been able to find any documentation on Android's sync services, so far
I just have the sources from the open source project which are a good start, but I am looking for architecture information, gotchas, etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you will have to roll your own - that's a private API.

Comment: I know it's private, and in my case it's Ok, since the code I'm working on will ship as part of the system ROM of the device, I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but I also don't want to work on it under false assumptions.

Comment: OK then, that's what it's built for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [an article](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/02/synchronization-in-android.html) related to the synchronization mechanism in Android.

Comment: That's a good start, at least to compare notes, thank you!

Comment: The article is a good start, but basically you have to go deep in the code yourself. At least, that was the only thing available in May 2009 when I did a research. Answer to your question also depends on what you need that synchronization mechanism for. For instance, if you are looking for a way to synchronize existing native content provider with remote location, you can not make much usage out of the existing API. However, if you are going to write a content provider on your own, and then use Android synchronization manager for it, you will be able to use it.

Comment: Yes, that's the direction I'm going, basically what I wanted is a way to validate my finding on the code. Thanks